# Connecting via VPN- can they see my sites in private browsing

Tags: networking, vpn

My concern is, I looked at a website on my local computer (job sites) and I'm very concerned the company can see this website and know I'm looking at other jobs.

My question is, when I use a VPN, does all internet traffic go via the VPN? And can they see the sites I visit if i use 'private browsing' in my web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite as 'cut and dry' as that I'm afraid.

If you go to a website to check your external IP (search google for whatismyip) when your not on the VPN and then again when you are connected to the VPN does this IP address change? If it does that means your browsing traffic is going down the VPN and therefore 'should' be hidden from anyone snooping...

However if the company runs intelligent firewall that monitor HTTP traffic or a proxy set in your internet options then web traffic can still be logged regardless of where it is being access from (VPN or local internet)...

Comment: I would also add that there is a possibility that they are running local monitoring software as well.