# Can my boss see what sites I visit when using a vpn from home to the office?

Tags: vpn

I know my boss could potentially see what sites I visit when I'm at the office if he would want to because I'm connected to the office WiFi or wired connection.

But what about when I'm at home on my own network and I have a VPN connection to the office? Tunnelblick is used for that on my OS X machine.

I think my main issue is that I don't know exactly how the VPN works. I only know that with it I can reach certain websites and svn repositories that are local to the office network. Is every http connection routed to my office or something? Or does it just change my IP maybe? Tunnelblick keeps track how many MB is received and send through the VPN and I'm curious how that exactly works as in how does it know what needs to be send over the VPN, but maybe that's another question on its own. My main concern is whether my boss can see my browsing behaviour that way.

Comment: VPNs can be set to either pipe all traffic through it, or just the traffic for that domain (research "Split Tunneling"). We can't possibly tell you which one your VPN configuration is using.  If you trace a route (ie: using `tracert`) to a site you're visiting, you can see if it's going through the VPN or not. If it is, then they can see you just like you were in the office.

Comment: Assume they can see everything you access while connected to the VPN.

Comment: Also see [Connecting via VPN- can they see my sites in private browsing](http://superuser.com/questions/813855/connecting-via-vpn-can-they-see-my-sites-in-private-browsing).

Comment: YES, and I need to talk to you about that. Come to my office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no absolutely sure way, to find out. Because there might be some software installed on your system, that always tracks your actions.

But you can find out, if your Traffic runs through the VPN.

Just visit whatsmyip.org with and without VPN, and compare. If it's the same IP, it looks like your traffic is not affected by the vpn.

If it's different, it's going through your vpn.

Comment: A simplier way to find out what packets go where is the `route` command (in a terminal). I think he'll see a route to the company via vpn and then a default route to his provider.