# Can my employer track my personal gmail messages

Tags: internet, gmail

I'm using Internet, shared through wireless network. Now, is there any possibility to track me If i am using gmail to send email?

Will my boss track my gmail account and see my content or outgoing messages using personal email instead of office email?

Comment: Yes; It's possible; The only way to be sure is to ask your employer if they are

Comment: Where does the boss come into this? You're on a Wi-Fi network, wherever that is. Are you on a work computer? Many holes in this

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/917892/can-my-boss-see-what-sites-i-visit-when-using-a-vpn-from-home-to-the-office

Comment: Don't use your personal email for work purposes, your boss doesn't have to hack your email  or have access to it, to find something like that out.  People have been fired for using a personal account for work purposes.  Keep your personal life separate from your personal life.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your bosses computer or your own?

**I am using my own computer**

If you are using your own computer, [GMAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) uses an [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) interface, which would make it quite difficult for your boss to see what was going on.

**I am using my bosses computer**

If you are using your bosses computer, then that computer could use [key-logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging) or other technologies to watch everything you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

gmail uses https, so your employer won't be able to read the content of your emails.

Unless they have put together a sophisticated man-in-the-middle attack to spoof gmail's security certificate for the express purpose of catching you. No normal employer would do this though, so don't worry unless you work for a criminal organisation with good tech skills.

They will however be able to see that you are visiting gmail, if they read the network logs. They could then ask why, and ask you not to if they were worried.

Lastly, if your employer is paranoid, and trying to spy on you, they could log key strokes from your keyboard either using software on your PC, or a bugged keyboard. Both are easy to set up, but pretty uncommon in most real world scenarios because anyone found doing so would lose all trust of their employees, and in some countries could potentially result in legal action due to breaches of privacy.

Comment: It is trivial to setup a MTIM proxy in a work environment.  Just saying.  A HTTPS connection to Google is only secure if your actually directly connected to Google

Comment: What if my employer uses ethernet switch (or any hardware) with network packet capture capability? Can they read my (assuming, ordinary and normal use of) Gmail?